# How do i add nodejs runtime layer layer to my Python Lambda on AWS?

Tags: python, node.js, amazon-lambda

### wscat test

In my Python lambda I want to use wscat which requires `node`:

`$ /opt/wscat-layer/bin/wscat`

```
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

### Question:

How do I add nodejs runtime to my Python lambda so i can execute wscat?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to place node in /opt/bin in order for it to be found by `wscat`.
So, your layer structure should look like this:

```
Later_1->
   /bin
       /node

Later_2->
   /wscat-layer       
       /package.json
       /bin
           /wscat
```

"As is" wscat will fail because it could not find dependencies like ws, read, commander , etc.

```
Layer_3->
   /lib
       /node_modules
           /commander
           /https-proxy-agent
           /...
```

Now it works:
`python3 pyNode.py export NODE_PATH=/opt/lib/node_modules\;/opt/wscat-layer/bin/wscat --version`

```
4.0.1
```